# Powershell ISE Crashes on Launch

Tags: powershell, windows-7, crash, powershell-ise

Not sure why, but today my workstation refuses to load the Powershell ISE.  I can load Powershell just fine and my cmdlets work.  I've tried loading both the 32bit and 64bit ISEs and both crash for the same reason.

This is the crashdump:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name: PowerShell   NameOfExe:
>   PowerShell_ISE.exe   FileVersionOfSystemManagementAutomation:
>   6.1.7600.16385   InnermostExceptionType: System.Xml.XmlException   OutermostExceptionType: System.Reflection.TargetInvocation
>   DeepestPowerShellFrame:
>   indows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main   DeepestFrame:
>   indows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main   ThreadName:
>   unknown   OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I couldn't find anything on google on this crash so I'm hoping someone here has some guidance.

Comment: I would start with checking .config file. Please check if you have C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe.config, and if it exists - try to move/ rename it, and run ISE again.

Comment: I checked out that directory (and thank you for posting) and I do not have a .config file there.

Comment: If you're using PS 3 can you try running `PowerShell_Ise -NoProfile`? If not then try temporally moving your `\$home\documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` somewhere else. If the ISE comes up then there's likely something in your profile conflicting with the ISE.

Comment: Could be an issue with your .NET installation...why not try adding the powershell_ise.exe.config file to force a certain CLR version like so: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
    </startup> 
</configuration>

Comment: Is it group policy?

Comment: Happened to me after manually updating PS to version 5 in Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 4):

This may be completely unrelated but in my case, I didn't understand much when I looked through [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to determine what was causing the crash as  a windows update (cherry picked by our Helpdesk team), broke my PowerShell ISE  launch, I also tried running without a profile. with Powershell_ISE -NoProfile

I followed the [techcommunity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/PowerShell-AMA/With-the-lastest-windows-update-KB4055532-breaks-ISE-why/m-p/144008#M41) thread and was able to fix my issue with Solution #3 GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont from [dotnet github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/53)

All I had to do was download [this font](https://dotnetbinaries.blob.core.windows.net/kbassets/KB4074906/GlobalUserInterface.CompositeFont) and update it at below locations, PowerShell ISE is a WPF Application and Fonts were corrupted by dotnet upgrade as a part of KB4074906

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\Fonts

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks..!

Comment: Yep. Confirming fixed. Thanks.